# jquery- first check for class name and then apply condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to detect the specific class from click event. and if the class is valid or according to my condition then i want to add or remove class according to that ..

```
<body class="clearfix with-menu with-shortcuts">
```

this class is showing the left navigation menu. so if i add the class menu-hidden.it will hide the menu. e.g

```
clearfix with-menu with-shortcuts menu-hidden
```

so in jquery i want to do something like this

```
  if('.clearfix.with-menu.with-shortcuts') is clicked {

     $(".clearfix.with-menu.with-shortcuts").addClass('menu-hidden'); 

  }and if (clearfix.with-menu.with-shortcuts.menu-hidden) is clicked 

      $(".clearfix.with-menu.with-shortcuts.menu-hidden").removeClass('menu-hidden');
```

so what actually i want to try to do  is when user first visit the page he will see the left   navigation menu,so if he press the icon which has a class `.clearfix.with-menu.with-shortcuts` the menu will be closed and then i save the cookie with the name "menuhidden" so when user visits again the page i will check first if the cookie is "menuhidden",if it is, menu remained closed otherwise show  the menu

Comment: Are you looking for the `.hasClass()` function?

Comment: Or maybe `.toggleClass()`?

Comment: you should use `.toggleClass( className, switch )` see switch parameter http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: It sounds more like they're looking for `toggleClass()`

Comment: i just want to check both the class whether it is hidden or not ..

Comment: @Pointy what my question is lets say now the menu is hidden and cookie is set to close-menu ... now whenever user is visiting the page he finds menu hidden... so now for example he wants to show the menu .. how can i detect the show event .. so that i can save the cookie to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<body class="clearfix with-menu with-shortcuts" id="menu">

$("#menu").click(function(){

   $(this).toggleClass('menu-hidden');

});
```